# Как правильно сделать поток при копирование файлов?

Tags: c#, потоки-данных

Пытаюсь сделать копирование файлов с ProgressBar. Всё в принципе работает но вот форма всё таки виснит при копирование. Может чего не так сделал при создании потока. Может кто помочь?

Сам исходник [вот](http://pastebin.com/kNkRWMMV)

P.S. Если надо могу и проект выложить

Answer (score 0):

Добавив в ваш код логирование можно сразу увидеть, что копированием на самом деле занимается главный поток и в этом ваша проблема.

Переделал метод:

```
private void cp(string path)
{
    string dest = @"C:\Temp";
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            var destPath = Path.Combine(dest, Path.GetFileName(path));
            File.Copy(path, destPath, true);
        }

        progresPart.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                                          {
                                              progresPart.Value++;
                                              progresPart.Update();
                                          }));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ошибка: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```